# Unable to create Hazelcast 3.0-RC1 on Amazon EC2 machines

Tags: amazon-ec2, hazelcast

I am trying to run Hazelcast cluster (version 3.0-RC1) on Amazon EC2 machine. I followed the example given in the documentation. The machines are not forming a cluster. Instead, I get the following message:

```
2013-07-16 17:58:41 com.hazelcast.system 11295 INFO  [10.168.30.154]:5701 [hzmap] 

Copyright (C) 2008-2013 Hazelcast.com
2013-07-16 17:58:41 com.hazelcast.instance.Node 11302 WARN  [10.168.30.154]:5701 [hzmap] com.hazelcast.impl.cluster.TcpIpJoinerOverAWS
2013-07-16 17:58:41 com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService 11304 INFO  [10.168.30.154]:5701 [hzmap] Address[10.168.30.154]:5701 is STARTING
2013-07-16 17:58:41 com.hazelcast.instance.Node 11636 WARN  [10.168.30.154]:5701 [hzmap] No join method is enabled! Starting standalone.
2013-07-16 17:58:41 com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService 11739 INFO  [10.168.30.154]:5701 [hzmap] Address[10.168.30.154]:5701 is STARTED
2013-07-16 17:58:42 com.hazelcast.partition.PartitionService 12812 INFO  [10.168.30.154]:5701 [hzmap] Initializing cluster partition table first arrangement...
```

Answer (score 1):

Bug has been resolved in RC-2.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a bug in Hazelcast 3.0-RC1

Node#createJoiner() method still using the old package name for TcpIPJoinerAWS class.

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("com.hazelcast.impl.cluster.TcpIpJoinerOverAWS");
```

Instead, the current package name for this class is:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("com.hazelcast.impl.TcpIpJoinerOverAWS");
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug is solved in Hazelcast 3 final.